Differentiable structures on topological Manifolds
I have to show that an homeomorphism $x:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ defines the canonical differentiable structure given by $\{(\mathbb{R}^n, {\rm id}_\mathbb R)\}$ if and only if $x$ and $x^{-1}$ are continuously differentiable.
I have problems understanding what this means and would be thankful for some explanations so I can solve the exercise. What does it mean that a chart defines a structure given by another chart? Does it mean that the charts are consistent with each other or do I have to show something else?
Thank you in advance!

$x$ is already a homeomorphism, so isn't it that $x$ and $x^{-1}$ must be continuous?

Yeah, no way is this phrased correctly.

@HeroZhang001 oh, I meant continuously differentiable! Thank you, I'll edit my question

Based on the context you provided, the meaning of "a chart defines a structure given by another chart" should be that these two charts are smoothly compatible, so these two charts give the same smooth structure.
What is "smoothly compatible"? Two charts $(U,\phi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ are said to be
smoothly compatible if either $U\cap V=\emptyset$ or the transition map $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism (i.e., $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}$ is bijective, and the component functions of $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}$ has continuous partial derivatives of all orders and has a smooth inverse map).
In your exercise, $(\mathbb R,x)$ and $(\mathbb R,{\rm Id})$ is smoothly compatible $\Longleftrightarrow$ $x^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism $\Longleftrightarrow$ $x$ and $x^{-1}$ are continuously differentiable.
